# Invalid date when using Moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I don't know how I can't find a similar issue in Stack Overflow but maybe I've missed them. Can't seem to convert this date format into a Moment. Trying to get back year format from this format "18/12/2009".

```
const year = moment(props.releaseDate).format("YYYY")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `"18/12/2009"` to `"12/18/2009"`

Comment: But that's how all my dates are coming in.